# How to load a file in an imported Java project?

Tags: java, file, path, project, relative-path

I'm developing a Java project that implements common functionalities. This project uses some xslt files. Actually I open these files using the relative path "file/xslt", and this works (the default path is "/" located in "PLACE1" within my filesystem, so the obtained path is "PLACE1/file/xslt").

Then I create a new project, import the previous project and try to use its functionalities, but obviously this doesn't work: within the library, the relative paths of the needed xslt files are calculated using the  default path of the second project (located in "PLACE2" within my filesystem, so the obtained path is "PLACE2/file/xslt").

How can I manage this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Put your xslt files in the same package as the class using them (or in the source root of the project) and then use Class.getResourceAsStream with path "file.xslt" or "/file.xslt" - this method searches classpath for the specified resource.

This way when the project is built resources (such as these xslt files) will be copied into appropriate directories with *.class files and placed in a jar file accordingly.

For example when class MyClass and file 1.xslt are in the same package:

```
InputStream xsltIn = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream ("1.xslt");
```

And if file 2.xslt is in the source root (default no-name package):

```
InputStream xsltIn = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream ("/2.xslt");
```